# Read uncommited data using transaction id in postgres after prepare transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, distributed-transactions

I have a use case as below:

1. Prepare a transaction and keep this transaction id.
2. Do some operations in multiple sessions using the same transaction id.
3. Do some operations in any external system.
4. Do some operations in multiple sessions using the same transaction id.
5. Commit the transaction for the transaction id.

I can achieve one level of multiple operations using  `prepare transaction 'demo1'`
but I am not sure if I can specify the transaction id in other queries.
I want to do something similar with Postgres.

```
begin
Update department set name='newDepartment' where id =4;
prepare transaction 'updateName';

//kill the session

//Do some operations based on this updated name.

// kill the session or start new session in another thread
//Update another table using the new name.

commit prepared 'updateName';
```

This operation is just an example but I want to achieve something similar but more complex.

Comment: Postgres never allows dirty reads (aka "read uncommitted")

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Why would you want to read uncommitted data for anything you describe above? Why do you want to prepare the transaction in the first place?

Comment: I have a UI service that provides the functionality to perform different actions Kind of a low code tool. So I want to query(update and select) a database, prepare a transaction and do some operations on the external service, based on the result of that query, and the user may add another nested action. The whole set of actions should either commit or rollback. I want to run this entire thing in a transaction. The catch here is I do not have a database directly accessible, it goes through a wrapper, and the wrapper can execute any query we specify.

Comment: So I do not have control over database connection,